# find only matched field value in table column in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to fetch matched field value from column (key and value)
match with key and get column value.

I tried with IF and CASE statement but produce same result
The table structure

The table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `UserInfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext NOT NULL,
  `created_on` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=111 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  

insert  into `UserInfo`(`id`,`user_id`,`key`,`value`,`created_on`,`updated_on`,`status`) values (69,11132,'country','India','','',1),(67,11132,'city','Gurgaon','','',1),(68,11132,'state','Haryana','','',1),(66,11132,'address','CyberHub','','',1),(64,11131,'state','Delhi','','',1),(65,11131,'country','India','','',1),(63,11131,'city','','','',1),(62,11131,'address','Lajpat Nagar','','',1),(60,11130,'state','Haryana','','',1),(61,11130,'country','India','','',1),(58,11130,'address','','','',1),(59,11130,'city','Gurgaon','','',1),(787,11130,'password','0192023a7bbd73250516f069df18b500','30-03-2016 06:58:18','30-03-2016 06:58:18',1),(788,11131,'password','04d237e63ebc1acbb3fcacf3e1a846cb','30-03-2016 06:58:18','26-04-2016 07:46:33',1),(789,11132,'password','0192023a7bbd73250516f069df18b500','30-03-2016 06:58:18','24-05-2016 11:47:35',1),(1123,11130,'parent','0','','',1),(1124,11131,'parent','0','','',1),(1125,11132,'parent','0','','',1),(2036,11136,'gcm_id','fLJ8vwS5yWc','04-05-2016 06:01:07','04-05-2016 06:01:07',1),(2035,11136,'push_id','fLJ8vwS5yWc:APA91bFO-hLW5uQqDQTABkilyOd9MzuMRhQMI8uNLRGh4fjaq3Bk1OvFmb7QFVKYpqqJZFPQ78Y1h0349IZuxq0EcxZ8VCHJOTOhhsqi1VxQ2A7TVLY-phDcN6sj80x8R7KoOocQKPLl','04-05-2016 06:01:07','04-05-2016 06:01:07',1),(2993,11570,'transaction_limit','100','16-09-2016 10:34:13','16-09-2016 10:34:13',1),(2992,11570,'otp','461178','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2991,11570,'password','1e28284f59e926547bb6793ad8723722','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2990,11570,'imei','353918057482479','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2989,11570,'push_id','dGxCE33MJgg:APA91bFCzSkvIDEcZcgmmSxVocFNZfLI8owLsdElmF-Et0wUH0mxUbQ9mIZDMjlhqClTOYiSxhSaVBdESwJW6J58hsyEF0LUMgXRTGdnEwWdbHJmm3EZuHDHzniMaJGcCKvALrcxtQt8','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2987,11570,'gender','Male','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2026,11136,'gcm_id','fLJ8vwS5yWc','03-05-2016 06:28:52','03-05-2016 06:28:52',1),(2025,11136,'push_id','fLJ8vwS5yWc:APA91bFO-hLW5uQqDQTABkilyOd9MzuMRhQMI8uNLRGh4fjaq3Bk1OvFmb7QFVKYpqqJZFPQ78Y1h0349IZuxq0EcxZ8VCHJOTOhhsqi1VxQ2A7TVLY-phDcN6sj80x8R7KoOocQKPLl','03-05-2016 06:28:52','03-05-2016 06:28:52',1),(2024,11136,'gcm_id','cU6PMImJ9Ms','02-05-2016 17:02:39','02-05-2016 17:02:39',1),(2023,11136,'push_id','cU6PMImJ9Ms:APA91bHA-a_joHtzEBgoAPRxRCXObeJLlCCNSxlCM-jBZKvSUEFvhLZEyqPbbsIDyWc2emZa1yBerOQLGXgzzNKZmcJYCgcF8KBdm9McVBiDKzU_OthjGnROZyTC5EvnI7Z4QivXnokA','02-05-2016 17:02:39','02-05-2016 17:02:39',1),(2022,11136,'gcm_id','cU6PMImJ9Ms','02-05-2016 16:38:55','02-05-2016 16:38:55',1),(2020,11136,'gcm_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ','02-05-2016 16:37:53','02-05-2016 16:37:53',1),(2021,11136,'push_id','cU6PMImJ9Ms:APA91bHA-a_joHtzEBgoAPRxRCXObeJLlCCNSxlCM-jBZKvSUEFvhLZEyqPbbsIDyWc2emZa1yBerOQLGXgzzNKZmcJYCgcF8KBdm9McVBiDKzU_OthjGnROZyTC5EvnI7Z4QivXnokA','02-05-2016 16:38:55','02-05-2016 16:38:55',1),(2019,11136,'push_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ:APA91bGskmvA5VVmxozMHKX3qHc16bdmk9h5gFTEPP8uFUYsO-doGCnkTE-ZtpMGeuuk2YCt3Ja56ey7nIga6aO7wpof2fI5zcgYdFACKvkcddNAlY4UhIO39tfyG3m4DZkmaLqw2Kxu','02-05-2016 16:37:53','02-05-2016 16:37:53',1),(2018,11136,'gcm_id','djRRW-PrS2Q','02-05-2016 16:30:02','02-05-2016 16:30:02',1),(2016,11136,'gcm_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ','02-05-2016 16:25:00','02-05-2016 16:25:00',1),(2017,11136,'push_id','djRRW-PrS2Q:APA91bFbB5SO0wY2TlGCZBmgbZUr0c1FXH5FE22YxOCf4tA7uM1V45T2cTY1aitIQKrf1bjrPB-zZUCDPNdL8-2SYnEawrFTdVjL5w1VuVI2kA89ixlK6jlpmNOoJ7wQnWqQoCFkcd9_','02-05-2016 16:30:02','02-05-2016 16:30:02',1),(2015,11136,'push_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ:APA91bGskmvA5VVmxozMHKX3qHc16bdmk9h5gFTEPP8uFUYsO-doGCnkTE-ZtpMGeuuk2YCt3Ja56ey7nIga6aO7wpof2fI5zcgYdFACKvkcddNAlY4UhIO39tfyG3m4DZkmaLqw2Kxu','02-05-2016 16:25:00','02-05-2016 16:25:00',1),(2014,11136,'gcm_id','djRRW-PrS2Q','01-05-2016 07:38:26','01-05-2016 07:38:26',1),(2013,11136,'push_id','djRRW-PrS2Q:APA91bFbB5SO0wY2TlGCZBmgbZUr0c1FXH5FE22YxOCf4tA7uM1V45T2cTY1aitIQKrf1bjrPB-zZUCDPNdL8-2SYnEawrFTdVjL5w1VuVI2kA89ixlK6jlpmNOoJ7wQnWqQoCFkcd9_','01-05-2016 07:38:26','01-05-2016 07:38:26',1),(2012,11136,'gcm_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ','01-05-2016 07:29:00','01-05-2016 07:29:00',1),(2011,11136,'push_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ:APA91bGskmvA5VVmxozMHKX3qHc16bdmk9h5gFTEPP8uFUYsO-doGCnkTE-ZtpMGeuuk2YCt3Ja56ey7nIga6aO7wpof2fI5zcgYdFACKvkcddNAlY4UhIO39tfyG3m4DZkmaLqw2Kxu','01-05-2016 07:29:00','01-05-2016 07:29:00',1),(2010,11439,'otp','467957','01-05-2016 07:04:42','16-08-2016 10:48:09',0),(2009,11438,'otp','631866','30-04-2016 09:36:54','06-05-2016 13:32:15',0),(2008,11438,'otp','586481','30-04-2016 09:22:55','06-05-2016 13:32:15',0),(2007,11438,'otp','971411','30-04-2016 09:19:52','06-05-2016 13:32:15',0),(2006,11136,'gcm_id','eNJISa-1OGA','30-04-2016 09:05:22','30-04-2016 09:05:22',1),(2005,11136,'push_id','eNJISa-1OGA:APA91bGB6m0d-RzoFUvw1SRsCIOEvfO3BjLUiMsZRdHnHlEGq6QKV9sVqCdLai25_dxTvUeuQVzFU5scKCaPvlDaG_VZ-V51t1AG4EEAtJdjGNQwhITF2eh0E24D_J9vPCQ3nIzanq8f','30-04-2016 09:05:22','30-04-2016 09:05:22',1),(2004,11445,'transaction_limit','2000','30-04-2016 09:03:41','30-04-2016 09:03:41',1),(2003,11445,'otp','230253','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(2002,11445,'password','25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(2001,11445,'push_id','ccPZg_PD7bo:APA91bFrUK8JPZfI6tSBKDgETeeI_aE6RA-FTFh6pS4fluVv6jHIVKUyDAEurIJWo49nWa52q6Zas7F2DI_KNkDX-HVq_TXuO36dRN9JditQVGR9HUq8avS5QEzYA2gwYjyo7Bosrsyz','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(2000,11445,'gcm_id','ccPZg_PD7bo','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(1999,11445,'gender','Male','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(1998,11445,'bank_name','DCB Bank','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(1997,11136,'gcm_id','cXK3F2L7Fcw','30-04-2016 08:37:01','30-04-2016 08:37:01',1)
```

I tried with query but its produce null column value as well
I want to ignore null value

```
SELECT
IF(ui.key='gender', ui.value,NULL)  gender,
IF(ui.key='password', ui.value,NULL) PASSWORD,
IF(ui.key='transaction_limit', ui.value,NULL) transaction_limit,

  ui.id,ui.user_id,ui.key,ui.value
FROM UserInfo ui
```

Comment: Have you tried using case

Comment: yes ! SELECT
  CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN ui.key='gender' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN ui.key='password' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN ui.key='transaction_limit' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END
  ) AS test,
  ui.id,ui.user_id,ui.key,ui.value
FROM UserInfo ui 
WHERE ui.user_id=11445

Comment: your expected output is <key, value>?
when key is column name

Comment: @Count yes dear

Comment: SELECT ui.id ,ui.user_id,ui.key , ui1.value
   FROM UserInfo ui JOIN  UserInfo ui1 ON ui1.key = ui.key;

Comment: does this solve your problem

Comment: On a side note: Why do you use a key/value table at all? Are your users so very different from each other? Do many have no gender or no password or no transaction limit? And even if that were the case, you could still have a column for each attribute and set it null where it doesn't apply. Key/value tables can be a real pain and I'd avoid them whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using join on the same table 
Try this one

```
SELECT ui.id ,ui.user_id,ui.key , ui1.value
FROM UserInfo ui JOIN  UserInfo ui1 ON ui1.key = ui.key;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 select
ui.user_id,
max(IF(ui.key='gender', ui.value,NULL))  gender,
max(IF(ui.key='password', ui.value,NULL)) PASSWORD,
max(IF(ui.key='transaction_limit', ui.value,NULL)) transaction_limit

 from UserInfo ui
group by ui.user_id
```

If you want only users that has values to the gener,PASSWORD and transaction_limit add  to the SQL :

```
having gender IS NOT NULL AND PASSWORD IS NOT NULL AND transaction_limit IS NOT NULL
```